# TF221122: An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

When I tried to create a Code Churn report in TFS 2015 analysis database, i have noticed that the data is quite old around months. I found out that in these kind of situations we can do the below:

[Manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube)

While running the GetProcessingStatus i got the error:

[Full Analysis Database Sync]: ---> AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType=Full, needCubeSchemaUpdate=True. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: TF221122: An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: Failed to Process Analysis Database 'Tfs_Analysis'. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully. The following system error occurred: This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Build', Name of 'Build' was being processed. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Build BK' attribute of the 'Build' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database was being processed. Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed. The following system error occurred: This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer. Errors in the high-level relational engine.......

Please help.

Comment: Which account are you using to create that Code Churn report? Did your account have any related SQL permission?

Comment: 6 month back i had provided admin permission to my personal account apart from the service account to TfsWarehouseAdministrator. Post that  i am not able to see any update to the analysis cube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this i had to recreate the Tfs_Analysis and Tfs_Warehouse databases after deleting them using SSMS.

Follow this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83db0db7-7118-40f3-af14-4e3871a7be7f/tf53010-the-following-error-has-occurred-in-a-team-foundation-component-or-extension-tf221122?forum=tfsadmin