# TFS Trust Relationship failed on Analysis Database Sync

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are receiving the error below for both the 'Full' and 'Incremental' Analysis Database Sync jobs in TFS 2015. I've searched for this error online and none of the answers worked in our situation.  Does anyone have experience with this along with a possible solution?

> [Full Analysis Database Sync]: --->
>   AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType=Full, needCubeSchemaUpdate=True. --->
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: TF221122: An
>   error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team
>   project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION. --->
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseException: Failed to
>   Process Analysis Database 'Tfs_Analysis'. ---> System.SystemException:
>   **The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed.** at
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed) at
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection
>   sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess) at
>   System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.OlapCreator.AddAccountToRole(Role
>   role, String accountName, Boolean throwOnError) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.OlapCreator.AddAccountsToRole(Database
>   database, String roleName, IEnumerable`1 accountNames, Boolean
>   ignoreAccountResolutionFailures) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.OlapCreator.CreateOrUpdateRoles(Server
>   server, Database database, IEnumerable`1 serviceAccountNames, Boolean
>   ignoreServiceAccountResolutionFailures, IEnumerable`1
>   readerAccountNames, Boolean ignoreReaderAccountResolutionFailures) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.OlapCreator.UpdateOlapSchema(Server
>   server, IEnumerable`1 readerAccountNames, WarehouseConfig
>   warehouseConfig) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.UpdateOlapSchema()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ProcessOlap(AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType
>   processingType, WarehouseChanges warehouseChanges, Boolean
>   lastProcessingFailed, Boolean cubeSchemaUpdateNeeded) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.TFSOlapProcessComponent.ProcessOlap(AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType
>   processingType, WarehouseChanges warehouseChanges, Boolean
>   lastProcessingFailed, Boolean cubeSchemaUpdateNeeded) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.AnalysisDatabaseSyncJobExtension.RunInternal(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.WarehouseJobExtension.Run(IVssRequestContext
>   requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime
>   queueTime, String& resultMessage) --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---

Comment: Saying "I searched for the problem and none of the suggestions worked" is not helpful. **What** have you tried? **What** did not work?

Comment: You're right.  That was very vague.  I checked the SIDs in the TfsWarehouseDataReader role in the Tfs_Analysis database on Analysis Services.  They were correct and all in the same domain as the TFS & database servers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem due to the error ID  TF221122. 
To narrow down the issue, suggest you could look in the OLAP log file, if there is useful information for what had happenеd there exactly. Usually the log is located under the OLAP folder of the MSAS installation (`\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSASX.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log`), and it could be called `msmdsrv.log` .

If there isn’t proper information, also check the **Event View** on server if there are some more error message.

Back to the error info, `The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trust domain failed`. It seems there's the trust issue in your two domains, please double check it first.

Besides also try to delete the whole Tfs_Analysis Database/Tfs_Warehouse Database, and run the “Rebuild” operation from the Application Tier following the steps below:

1. Open Team Foundation Server Administration console.
2. Go to Reporting and there is “Start Rebuild”.

Note that this action could be used to rebuild your data warehouse and analysis database for the cube. Once you start it, it will take offline, delete, and rebuild both your Warehouse and Analysis Services databases. Based on the amount of data you have n your TFS DB, it could take significant amount of time to complete these jobs. The reports will not show any data until the above databases are not rebuilt successfully.

Take a look at below similar issue:

- [TFS2010 TF221122: An error occurred running job Full Analysis
  Database Sync: the trust relationship between the primary domain and
  the trusted domain failed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d2636b5d-d664-48b5-ac1f-776030d80bb9/tfs2010-tf221122-an-error-occurred-running-job-full-analysis-database-sync-the-trust-relationship?forum=tfsreporting)
- [TF221122: An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544242/tf221122-an-error-occurred-running-job-full-analysis-database-sync-for-team-pro)

Comment: Thanks for the links!  I will try to rebuild the data warehouse and analysis database.  I'm crossing my fingers...

Comment: I tried the rebuild several times to no avail.  We still have the 'trust relationship' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Our server support group found in the Event Viewer on the TFS server that the password was not valid for the user ID in three of the TFS services.  I had changed the password for our TFS service account a while ago, but apparently did not update it in the services.

The "trust relationship" failure was resolved once I corrected the TFS service account password in the services below.

1. Team Foundation Ssh Service
2. Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent
3. Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host 2015